# OCR: Low-contrast/noisy regions

Tags: opencv, ocr, watermark, noise

I am trying to identify the 17-character code shown below.

[image]

I am currently using OpenCV for my pipeline:
(1) convert to B & W image
(2) compute gradient image
(3) Otsu Thresholding
(4) Find contours
(5) Find bounding boxes of contours

It works very well when the image is relatively clean. In the example above, I am able to detect "H26A838778". Does anyone have any idea how to handle the left side of the image, where the contrast is low and the watermark adds noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to threshold your image using [Simple Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Since the color among the characters is the same or similar and their color value is higher than the background (more whitish), you can try to find the threshold color value which will keep the color of the characters white and everything else as black. In the following example (Java code), this number is 140.

```
Mat original = Imgcodecs.imread("pathToOriginalImage");
Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(original, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);
Mat binary = new Mat();
Imgproc.threshold(original,binary,140,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```

**Convert to Grey Scale**

[image: gray scale]

**Thresholding**

[image: binary]

**OCR should give some good results now.**